# How to pass FileList through promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-promise

I have the following code. I use the fileList variable which is a FileList which contains only one file. Then I pass it

```
foo(fileList) {
    this.props.bar({ fileList })
        .then((res) => 
            this.props.doSomething({ fileList });
        })
}
```

Then in a different file

```
doSomething({ fileList }) {
...
}
```

My problem is that before bar() is entered fileList contains one file. Then inside of the .then fileList appears to be empty resulting in doSomething getting no files. Also, after the bar promise completes the fileList contains the file again.

Is this a scope issue? How do I fix this?

Comment: how is `fileList` generated/created?

Comment: what you describe is impossible - the same `fileList` is passed to `this.props.bar` and to `this.props.doSomething`

Comment: It is being taken from an <input type="file">.

Comment: I agree I do not see why this would be happening.

Comment: Just want to point out that it should be `this.props.doSomething(res)`, not `this.props.doSomething({ fileList })` as you've already returned `fileList` and turned it into a promise response.

Comment: @JossClassey - how do you know what it should be? `fileList` is **not** a "promise response", whatever the heck that is

Comment: @JaromandaX I was just saying that _if it was a promise_, then `res` would be the result of the resolved promise, not fileList. I wasn't commenting on anything other than that.

Comment: yes, but you said "it should be  `this.props.doSomething(res)`" - but there's no reason to suspect it SHOULD be that. `res` may not be what the OP want to pass to `doSomething` at all

Answer (score 0):

So I found out what was wrong. I wanted to thank everyone for helping.

This foo was being called asynchronously. So, fileList contained one file for the first call to bar() but by the time doSomething() was called fileList was actually changed in the method that called foo() originally.